# how to use Gridview with a variable number of Imagebuttons?

Tags: android

I need some help for my app. I need a view containing an undefined number of ImageButtons based on a variable. That is, supposing the variable is set to 3, then 3 Imagebutton should be shown on the screen. Is there any way I can build this? I'm trying it using GridView, but it seems that you must provide a fixed number of images to fill `Integer[] mThumbIds`. Besides, I need the image to change on click event and this doesn't seem possible to accomplish using the GridView.

Another question related to the topic, is there any way I could use an Imagebutton with more than two states? I'd like the Image to display the effect of being establishing a connection when the user taps on it, something like those red stripes that come from the surface of the icon to the outside as if sending a wireless signal, I don't know if you know what I mean...

Comment: what is mThumbIds and where does it comes from ?

Comment: I'm following the example from the android website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: that's an example. it doesn't prevent you from reading the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView will work perfectly for what you want, just use a custom adapter like you would for a  ListView, override the getView() method and set your onClickListener there.